# pandas Groupby matrix of one condition based on the other condition bin by time

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, heatmap

I have a Dataset like below that divided to two desired group by below condition

| Employee No | Event date | Event Description | Quarter | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 2021-10-12 | First Hire | Q4 | 21 |
| 103 | 2021-11-02 | First Hire | Q4 | 21 |
| 102 | 2022-01-01 | Terminated | Q1 | 22 |
| 102 | 2021-12-12 | Shift Change | Q4 | 21 |
| 101 | 2021-12-03 | First Hire | Q4 | 21 |
| 103 | 2021-11-05 | Terminated | Q4 | 21 |
| 101 | 2021-12-04 | Terminated | Q4 | 21 |
| 105 | 2022-02-26 | First Hire | Q1 | 22 |
| 106 | 2022-02-26 | First Hire | Q1 | 22 |
| 102 | 2022-03-29 | Second Hire | Q1 | 22 |
| 107 | 2021-05-04 | First Hire | Q2 | 21 |
| 108 | 2022-04-04 | First Hire | Q2 | 22 |
| 109 | 2022-03-03 | Terminated | Q1 | 22 |
| 109 | 2021-12-29 | First Hire | Q4 | 21 |
| 109 | 2022-04-01 | Second Hire | Q2 | 22 |
| 109 | 2022-01-10 | Shift Change | Q1 | 22 |

```
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        {
            'Employee No': [102,103,102,102,101,103,101,105,106,102,107,108,109,109,109,109],
            'Event date': ['2021-10-12', '2021-11-02', '2022-01-01', '2021-12-12','2021-12-03','2021-11-05','2021-12-04','2022-02-26','2022-02-26','2022-03-29','2021-05-04','2022-04-04','2022-03-03','2021-12-29','2022-04-01','2022-01-10'],
            'Event Description': ['First Hire', 'First Hire', 'Terminated', 'Shift Change','First Hire','Terminated ','Terminated','First Hire','First Hire','  Second Hire','First Hire','First Hire','Terminated','First Hire','Second Hire','Shift Change'],
            'Quarter': ['Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q4','Q4','Q4','Q4','Q1','Q1','Q1','Q2','Q2','Q1','Q4','Q2','Q1'],
'Year': ['21', '21', '22', '21','21','21','21','22','22','22','21','22','22','21','22','22']
        }
    )

# First hired 
cond1 = df["EventDescription"].eq("FirstHire")

# Terminated later after first hired
cond2 = (
   
    df["Event Description"].eq("Terminated")
    & df["employee No"].isin(df.loc[cond1, "employee No"])
)

df[cond2]
```

I need to visualize as a table (Heatmap or Pivot Table ) distribution for Terminated by quarter and the year at vertical and first Hire at Horizontal by Quarter and the year.
the value at each cell will be unique counts of Cond 2 based on cond 1 date Quarter and year   .
How we can use groupby or crosstab in pandas or any other solution ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, so just to check: you want two histograms, with time on the x-axis. Plot #1 shows the number of events meeting condition 1 over time, and the plot #2 shows the number of events meeting condition 2 over time. Is that right?

Comment: Thank you for your reply .It could be a histogram but I came up with a pivot table matrix that shows count of events meeting condition 1 over time and number of events meeting condition 2 over time at each cell.

Comment: Can you share code to generate data you have shared?